# PowerPoint 2007 - How to use Application.AfterPrintPresentation event handler?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, add-in

so I've found that PowerPoint 2007 event handlers on the Application level.

```
  For example   even  Application.PresentationPrint
```

but the real question is , how do use event  handler "Application.AfterPresentationPrint "
 ,  can I use it? 
To tell you my scenario, what I want is to insert dynamic text into a few textboxes. after finished from print  the Presentation

Where do I start?

i am using c#2010 with power point 2007.

Comment: Where do you find an AfterPresentationPrint event documented?  So far as I know, there isn't one.  But the PresentationPrint event fires after the presentation is printed, so it should suffice for what you want to do, I'd think.

Comment: This is exactly the problem, the absence of the event after printing
How do I deal with that?

Comment: As I said, the PresentationPrint event fires AFTER printing.  It's badly named, sure.  But it should do what you want.